# Ubuntu, POSIX mq_receive not blocking when it should

Tags: c, posix

I'm stuck at start point with my POSIX queue:

what (I think) should be blocking isn't blocking at all, and the loop keeps spinning.
I am trying to have a process blocked on a `mq_receive` until some message arrives, but looks like the call always receives an empty message from the queue(but there are not yet any clients sending messages). The queue is correctly opened with the default settings of `mq_flags=0`.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    mqd_t qd;
    qd = mq_open("/tempqueue", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
    if (qd == (mqd_t) -1){
        printf("Problemz");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("Coda creata\n");
    }

    char buf[400];

    while(1){
        mq_receive(qd, buf, 400, NULL);
        printf("Ricevo: %s.\n", buf);
    }

    mq_close(qd);
    mq_unlink("/tempqueue");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the return value!

It's almost certainly "-1" ... and which point you can call "perror()" or check "errno" for the underlying error:

Comment: I am checking the return value here `if (qd == (mqd_t) -1)` but the return value is not '-1', in fact, the program goes ahead until the while loop and starts receiving.

Comment: @VladSaftoiu You need to check the return value of mq_receive inside the while loop

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out: `perror()` returned `Message too long` wich then took me to the problem in the buffer size: `buf[400]` should be `buf[8192]` because the `msgsize` of the queue is 8192.